# Quantized spacetime structure?

Tags: spacetime, universe, discrete

Is quantized spacetime more like a chessboard or a matrix of lights? I have heard two analogies, the light bulb one appears to allow for movement whilst the chess piece one seems to violate zenos paradox. Whilst is a better example?

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/#Sta